# JavaScript function scope question

Tags: javascript, return

Please refer to the following code

```
function createCar(sColor, iDoors, iMpg) {
    var oTempCar = new Object;
    oTempCar.color = sColor;
    oTempCar.doors = iDoors;
    oTempCar.mpg = iMpg;
    oTempCar.showColor = function () {
        alert(this.color)
    };
    return oTempCar;
}
var oCar1 = createCar("red", 4, 23);
var oCar2 = createCar("blue", 3, 25);
oCar1.showColor(); //outputs “red”
oCar2.showColor(); //outputs “blue”
```

My question is whats the main use of return in the above function? Is it to return the object created by the function and assign all its properties to oCar1 and oCar2 [in our example] coz without return this function fails.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Is there still anything else you wanna know?

Comment: Yes, you should always sanely indent code out of hubris.

Answer (score 0):

It is to return the new object created (`oTempCar`).

Without the `return`, `undefined` would be implicitly assigned to `oCar1` and `oCar2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code correctly indented.

As you can see, the `return` is part of the `createCar` function.  Without the return, it will return `undefined` and thus `oCar1` and `oCar2` will not be correctly set and the `showColor()` method will not exist on the variables.

Just to state the obvious; it is the parentheses `{}` that determine scope.  The `return` belongs to the scope of the parentheses `{}` it is inside, in this case the `creatCar` scope/parentheses.

```
function createCar(sColor, iDoors, iMpg) {
    var oTempCar = new Object;
    oTempCar.color = sColor;
    oTempCar.doors = iDoors;
    oTempCar.mpg = iMpg;
    oTempCar.showColor = function () {
        alert(this.color)
    };
    return oTempCar;
}
var oCar1 = createCar("red", 4, 23);
var oCar2 = createCar("blue", 3, 25);
oCar1.showColor(); //outputs “red”
oCar2.showColor(); //outputs “blue”
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCar(sColor, iDoors, iMpg) {
    this.color = sColor;
    this.doors = iDoors;
    this.mpg = iMpg;
    this.showColor = function () {
      alert(this.color)
    };
}
var oCar1 = new createCar("red", 4, 23);
var oCar2 = new createCar("blue", 3, 25);
oCar1.showColor(); //outputs “red”
oCar2.showColor(); //outputs “blue”
```

it is the same with this.you need a "new".

Answer (score 0):

what you have there is a constructor.  It is a special kind of function to make JavaScript more readable to those C and Java people.

How is it special you ask?
Well for one, it is just for the reason you mentioned without returning the object your are playing with.  If you return nothing, it returns the value of `this` an empty object.  Normally in a function `this` refers to `window` or other things based on situation like `o.method` `this` would refer to `o` under normal situations.  In your case, this is a constructor and you called it with new, so `this` refers to a new empty object with prototype set to `createCar.prototype` and prototype.constructor pointing to `createCar.prototype.constructor`, in your case this is `createCar`.  As the above answers point out, if you modify this you will get the behavior you seem to expect which is things to just work.

These answers still look like C code, so how do we make it fun JavaScript code?  Try this:

```
function createCar(sColor, iDoors, iMpg) {

    this.color = sColor;
    this.doors = iDoors;
    this.mpg = iMpg;
    //return this; //Not needed, but is what happens under the covers
}

createCar.prototype = {

    showColor: function(){

        alert( this.color );
    }
}

var oCar1 = createCar("red", 4, 23);
var oCar2 = createCar("blue", 3, 25);
oCar1.showColor(); //alerts “red”
oCar2.showColor(); //alerts “blue”
```

AGAIN, agh so boring!  Lets do something more fun

```
createCar.prototype.showColor.call( oCar1 );  //Alerts "red"
createCar.prototype.showColor.call( new createCar( "red" ) );  //Also alerts red
```

TBH, I never use constructors, but it is a good way to get your feet wet.